# NSFetchedResultsController extra section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tried to add an extra section to my `UITableView` which is managed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I want the first section, section 0, to only contain one row and this is fine. But when the tableview gets populated from my core data model and through the `NSFetchedResultsController`, it "thinks" that it can use the first section to show data. What I want is that, it starts to populate the data from section 1 and not from section 0.

This is my code:

```
#pragma mark UITableView/NSFetchResultsController Helper Methods

- (NSIndexPath *)mapIndexPathFromFetchResultsController:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];

    return indexPath;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)mapIndexPathToFetchResultsController:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section];


    return indexPath;
}


#pragma mark UITableView Delegate & DataSource Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;

    NSArray *sections = [self.fetchedResultsController sections];


    if ( section < [sections count] )
    {
//ObjectAtIndex .. How can I trick NSFetchedResultsController to think that section 1 is section 0? 
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];
        numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

        if (section == 0) {
            numberOfRows++;
        }

}

   return numberOfRows;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *normalCellIdentifier = @"DetailTableCell";

    static NSString *subMenuCellIdentifier = @"DetailSubMenuTableCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:subMenuCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:subMenuCellIdentifier];
    }

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {

            DetailCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:normalCellIdentifier];

            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[DetailCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:normalCellIdentifier];
            }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Test"; 


        return cell;
        }
    }

    SubMenuGroup *group = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self mapIndexPathToFetchResultsController:indexPath]];

    for (SubMenus *subMenu in group.menus) {
        cell.textLabel.text = subMenu.name;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = subMenu.info; 
    }





    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {

         return 80; 

        }

    }


    return 50;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{

    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] == 0) {
        return 1;
    }else {
        return ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] + 1);
    }


}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 20;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    if (section) {


        NSArray *sections = [self.fetchedResultsController sections];

        if ( section < [sections count] )
        {

            id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];
            return [[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0] name];


        }else {

              return @"TODO";

        }


    }

    return nil;
}
```

How can I trick `NSFetchedResultsController` to think that section 1 is section 0, so no rows is added to the first section (But in the rows own section)?

Illustration, how the tableview is currently populated: [image]

Comment: If it serves your purpose, you could use self.tableView.tableHeaderView to display your custom cell. that would be the least effort on your part.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that isn't a solution at this point, since I already is using this to show other content :/